# How to solve CORS error in a unity webgl build

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine

I have a project that needs to connect to amazon web server with unity. While everything is working properly in the editor. When I get webgl build, I get CORS error.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://yoururl.amazonaws.com/prod/auth/signin' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

This is sign in code:

```
string userData = "{\"username\":\"" + username + "\",\"password\":\"" + password + "\"}";
    byte[] bodyRaw = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userData);

    UnityWebRequest client = UnityWebRequest.Post($"{OriginURL}/auth/signin",userData);
    ResetHeader(client);
    client.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
    client.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
    client.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    
    await client.SendWebRequest();

    if (client.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Error: " + client.error);
    }
    else
    {
        string responseContent = client.downloadHandler.text;

        if (client.responseCode == 200)
        {

            var signInResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SignInResponse>(responseContent);

            SessionManager.Instance.IdToken = signInResponse.IDToken;
            SessionManager.Instance.AccessToken = signInResponse.AccessToken;
            SessionManager.Instance.RefreshToken = signInResponse.RefreshToken;

            //SetHeader();
            onSuccess?.Invoke(signInResponse);
        }
        else
        {
            var signInError = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SignInError>(responseContent);

            onFailed?.Invoke(signInError);
        }
    }
```

- I allowed CORS mode in AWS.

Comment: in addition to the error you get could you additionally include the code that is causing it?

Comment: Otherwise I guess we can not do much more then refer you to the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/webgl-networking.html) and [Relative questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=Unity+WebGL+CORS)